# Python requests.put cannot update object

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I'm trying to request put into my API built using Django.
When I'm requesting from IDLE I'm not getting my objects updated, but when I use postman and I make request on the same url with the same JSON it works. I don't get the point because the url and JSON are the same.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json


url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rentals/35/"
custom_json = {"client": "dsa", "bike_id_number": ["483KIS5O4D", "473JDS93DF", "837JFIE945"]}

myobj = json.dumps(custom_json)

print(myobj)
requests.put(url, data = myobj)
```

Screen from Postman with copied url and JSON from my Python Code:
https://ibb.co/rmPRtPj

Comment: Use `requests.put(url, json=custom_json)`. That takes care of setting the Content-Type header to value application/json. Otherwise with your current way you'll have to set it.

Comment: It worked !! I was trying to fix it for 2 hours. Thanks a lot dude :0

Comment: if you add JSON in `data=` then you may have to add also `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`. If you use `json=` then it adds this header automatically. BTW: in `Postman` you have button/link `Code` which can generate code for different languages and it can also generate code for Python with `requests` - but it uses `data=` and `headers=` instead of `json=`

Answer (score 2):

You may have to specify the `Content-Type: application/json` header from your Python code, or you could pass your Python dict directly to `requests` via the `json` keyword param (it sets the header automatically for you this way).

```
requests.put(url, json = custom_json)
```

[Source](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) (what applies to POST here, also applies to any other method with a body)